# How do you get Windows Error Reporting (WER) to save memory dumps for hangs?

Tags: windows-10, memory-dump, windows-error-reporting

WER is creating memory dumps after an application hangs. When Windows shows the dialog box ***ApplicationName* is not responding**, if the user clicks **Close the program**, I can see .hdmp files being created in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp`. After it sends them to Microsoft, this folder is created: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppHang_WindowsFormsApp5_823dc9208bf3a14f898f39469b7b6a0c6f17c7_3db8b24d_07a39f1b`. However, this folder only has a .wer file with a summary.

Can Windows Error Reporting be configured to keep the memory dumps capturing the unresponsive application on the local disk?

I have already tried `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps`, but it is only creating dumps for crashes, not hangs.

Comment: use procdump -h to generate dumps for hangs: https://collaborationhelp.cisco.com/article/en-us/WBX85638

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a REG_SZ value called `CorporateWerServer` in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\`, and set it's value to empty string. Since Windows cannot contact the Corporate WER Server, the hang dumps will remain in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\`

Comment: This is the only thing that worked reliably for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ConfigureArchive setting of WER and set it to '2' [All data]. That will capture and archive all the data (instead of just Report.wer).

See *ConfigureArchive* at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wer/wer-settings.

From an elevated prompt, run:

```
Reg add "hklm\software\microsoft\windows\windows error reporting" /f /t REG_DWORD /v ConfigureArchive /d 2
```

Setting Corporate WER server would cause all the crash/hang reports to sit on your device and they will never reach Microsoft. That may not be the ideal solution.

Comment: Hi, I cannot remember if we tested `ConfigureArchive`, but I'll verify it works and change the accepted answer.  Changing `CorporateWerServer` to empty string definitely was a hack - `ConfigureArchive` of `2` sounds much closer to what we were looking for.

Comment: This didn't work for me even though I also set the value in HKCU.