# *.wer instead *.dmp files generated

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-10

I am trying to debug an app which crashes after a certain times, and this seems happen only on a specific machine.
I don't exactly understand why it generates a ***.wer file** instead a ***.dmp** file. I have set my own `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()`.
My question is, can a third party device driver cause this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get Windows Error Reporting (WER) to save memory dumps for hangs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540110/how-do-you-get-windows-error-reporting-wer-to-save-memory-dumps-for-hangs)

Comment: The point of SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() is to *not* get WER involved.  Call MiniDumpWriteDump() to generate the DMP file.  Then TerminateProcess() so WER won't step in.

Comment: @hans,  yes I want dmp files, but it does not. Simple errors, wrong pointers etc are catched, and generate dmp files. But it seems errors in device driver are not catched, the wer file give me only a hint to the wrong module. Can this be?